# PHP JSON_DECODE not working with special characters

Tags: php

I try to decode a json file and put it into an array but as soon as there is a special character the json_decode stops working:

```
$json_file_path = 'creds2.json';
$json_contents = file_get_contents($json_file_path);
$data = json_decode($json_contents, true);
var_dump($data);
```

returns NULL when creds2.json is:

```
{
"TEMP_REGEX": "[0-9]{2,3}[\.]{1}[0-9]{1}",
"HUMI_REGEX": "[0-9]{2,3}[\.]{1}[0-9]{1}"
}
```

but it returns the right value when it's:

```
{
"example": "examples",
"test123": "test123"
}
```

I already went around the forums but couldn't find a solution. Even ChatGPT couldn't help me out on this one.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. The backslashes in the JSON file need to be escaped. It should be `[\\.]`

Comment: Whoever created the file didn't use a JSON library, they wrote ad hoc code that doesn't implement all the rules of JSON. They need to fix their code.

Comment: @Barmar wow jeez I'm an idiot. Yea im basically working in a text editor because the server my school runs doesn't have a proper IDE. I just put it in VS Code and it showed me the error right away. Thanks

Comment: Don't put SOLVED In the title. If you have a solution, post an answer and accept it. If the question is moot, delete it.

Comment: You need to check whether decoding worked. You have `json_last_error()` and `json_last_error_msg()`, or you can do `json_decode($json_contents, true, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put another `\`. It is supposed to be `[\\.]`.